Restricting access to a Google App Engine backend service to a single domain, without authentication
I have a webApp that is composed of a frontend (hosted on AWS Amplify) and a Node.js backend API (hosted on GAE). The app works just fine, but I need to ingore requests to my backend API endpoints that do not come from the frontend.
My first idea was to configure CORS on the backend, but that only works partially, because CORS is only enforced in browsers, and it's still possible to send requests to the "secret" endpoints.
I then tried to configure Google's Idendity-Aware Proxy on my backend, enable "allowed domains" and pass my frontend's domain as the only value in the allow-list. This also failed, causing the requests from the frontend to be responded to with 401 - Unauthorized (Invalid IAP credentials).
Is this because I added no authentication between frontend and backend? Does IAP's allowed domains list only work if the requests come from an authenticated entity?
Is it even possible in principle to filter out requests by domain without having some form of authentication?

This question is similar to: How to reject http/https request if not coming from allowed website or source. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
